# Communication between client and server in Angular 2+

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-forms, nodemailer

I am using NodeMailer for mail service. I have to get an email address from a field in client side and send that value to app.js where my nodemailer code resides.

client side

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.forgotForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: this.email,
  });
}

sendmail() {
}
```

app.js, Nodemailer code (I have to get email id for to address here)

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    to: '',
    subject: 'Test Mailer',
    text: 'I am testing Nodemailer to send email.',
};
```

Comment: so what is the problem , who/what is stopping you to get the info from angular form

Comment: nothing is stopping bro as i am new to Angular I have no idea how to send a value from client to server side.

Comment: Read about HTTP request in angular :
https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @ChrisFelix i have added a few links that can help you get sorted hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the link bro

Answer (score 0):

You Should Consider Looking/ Learning Angular and then going into forms . and then into http modules which will help you post data to services

**This is a gist not the actual answer**

There are a lots of ways to get this done , using normal inputs and getting data from that input using button control or using Forms[the best approach] as you might have other details to send as well.

There are two kind of froms in Angular [**Template Driven**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) or [**Reactive Forms**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive).

After getting the details in your form you will need to post it to a Rest service i am guessing. For that you will need to look at Angular [**Http Client**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services) Module

Please look at those links for more detailed Info on them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use services in angular in order to do this. in terminal set the path to a folder where you want create service, and then use the command `ng generate service <service_name>` . This will create a file service_name.service.ts. You can refer https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/overview/ or https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 for more details.

You can use APIs along with http methods get, post, put, delete etc. to complete your task.

In respective component.ts file create a variable email like:

```
email =string;
```

In the html file bind the input field with ngModel as:

```
[(ngModel)]="email"
```

Then make a function in service.ts that accepts email as arguments

```
endMail(email) {
//make api call using http method(say post)
// supply email
  let url = <APIURL>
  return http.post(url, {email: email});
}
```

Again in component.ts import this service and instantiate in constructor and use a method to call service

Comment: Sure bro. As you know basically we are dealing with RESTful applications, and there we will be having folders like model, controller and routes. Suppose we are written a code (say to send mail) in server side. Now client side need to send data (parameters like mail id, message) to server side. For this APIurls (paths egs: /api/sendmail) will help. In server side, in routes we will do necessary actions. You might be aware of this for sure

Comment: how do i receive it in server side bro (i.e) in To mail address

Comment: very informative bro. how do i receive it in server side bro (i.e) in To mail address

Comment: Have you got idea about API urls? It will look like  http://localhost:8000/users, or  http://localhost:8000/sendmail

Comment: return http.post(`http://localhost:3000/sendmail, email: email); I have done like this, i could send my mail but i don't how to get the email value bro for To address

Comment: If you have node background you might be aware of render method which will help to finish the task

Comment: not like that params need to set how you deal it in back end, the type you are expecting